# Google Spreadsheet script "Cell reference out of range"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a range in a google spreadsheet script.

```
var thisClientOutputRange = outputSheet.getRange(thisClientStartRow,thisClientStartColumn, monthsToSim + 3, 1);
Logger.log(thisClientOutputRange.getA1Notation());
```

The output is:

```
[15-10-29 18:43:06:461 GALT] B7:B57
```

Which is exactly the range I intended to address for this specific client (currently looping on in a for loop).

I can do

```
var thisClientOutputNameRange = thisClientOutputRange.getCell(1,1);
thisClientOutputNameRange.setValue(thisClientName);
```

And I can see the value correctly at `B7`. Now the problem is if I try to do

```
var thisClientOutputNameRange = thisClientOutputRange.getCell(1,2);
```

I get the error `Cell reference out of range` at exactly this line. I need to write something at `C7`.

According to the [getCell](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getCell(Integer,Integer)) documentation:

> `var range = sheet.getRange("B2:D4");`
>
> // The row and column here are relative to the range.
>
> // `getCell(1,1)` in this code returns the cell at B2, B2

I must have a very stupid mistake, but I can't find it. Any idea what could be going wrong with my logic?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range's getCell(row,column) method returns a cell from the range. The row and column coordinates are relative to the range. In your example of getCell(1,2), row=1 and column=2 represents the cell at the first row and second column of the range. However, the range B7:B57 only has one column. Thus, the cell reference is outside of the range.

Comment: as simple as that. Thanks. My mistake was in the `outputSheet.getRange` declaration, where I switched the last 2 arguments.

Comment: It should be: `var thisClientOutputRange = outputSheet.getRange(thisClientStartRow, thisClientStartColumn, 1,monthsToSim + 3);`